# In Javascript, does console.log on an object call toString?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, tostring

```
Array.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "testing";
}

a1 = [1,2,3];

console.log(a1); // returns [1,2,3]
console.log(a1.toString()); // returns "testing"
```

why is that? How does the first log print out values? I thought it used the toString method?

Comment: Which console are you talking about? There's no specification for how consoles work. They programmed however the developer's decided to program them.

Comment: I see. This is for firefox. Didn't know it was browser specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firefox(both Firebug and Dev Web Console), Chrome: No

For IE: Yes