# console.log of BSON objects in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bson

I'm confused about the way console.log displays ObjectId() objects from native MongoDB driver for NodeJS.

I print the `adslot` document from MongoDB with console.log:

```
db.collection('adslots').findOne({_id: adslotId}, (err, adslot)=>{
    console.log( adslot );
}
```

and the output is

```
adslot:
{ _id: 57ef0b9b26d1d77b606bf271,
  name: 'cspop',
  width: 1,
  height: 1,
  elemId: 'dummy',
  active: true,
  updated: 2016-10-01T01:04:27.597Z }
```

`_id` looks like a hex number. However, _id is ObjectId because:

```
console.log( "adslot:\n" + adslot._id.constructor.name );
```

gives

```
adslot:
ObjectID
```

In spite of `adslot` having constructor of `ObjectId` calling `isValid()` ( http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html#.isValid ) on it gives an error:

```
console.log('adslot:');
console.log( adslot._id.isValid() );
```

results:

```
adslot:
/home/vlad/arbsrv/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: adslot._id.isValid is not a function
```

So, why does `console.log()` prints `_id` as a number and not as an object? Is `toString()` somehow called automatically on the `_id`?

And why if `_id` is instance of `ObjectId`, `isValid()` is not defined on it?

Comment: Ok, isValid is static method of ObjectId and is used as ObjectId.isValid(adslot._id) which returns true. The question about console.log remains.

Answer (score 0):

`isValid` is defined on the `ObjectId` itself and not its prototype. An instance of the ObjectId will not have this method. Try calling it as `ObjectId.isValid()`

Take the following for example:

```
function ObjectId(){}

ObjectId.isValid = function(){
    return true;
}

ObjectId.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    return 'hello';
}

var a = new ObjectId();
a.sayHi(); // hello
a.isValid(); // raises exception

ObjectId.isValid(); // true
```

**why does console.log() prints _id as a number and not as an object?**

Short answer, yes it calls the toString() on it. For more details check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215379/does-console-log-invokes-tostring-method-of-an-object). Also from what i understand, the ObjectId prototype has a toString method defined on it which return the _id value as a string.

Comment: According to the answer you mentioned: "Console API in FF calls toString() on the argument only if the argument type is not one of  {undefined,null,object,set,map} types." But typeof _id returns "object" so I don't understand why console.log() automatically calls toString() on it. Is it special patch for Objectid() objects in NodeJs?