# Add toString to backbone-model-like objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tostring

I've recently changed from Java backend to JS frontend. We use a backbone like object structure (at least that's what my colleagues told me) and I wondered if there is a way to override `toString()` (e.g. should be called from `console.log`).

This is what our models looks like

```js
// namespace
var De = {};
De.Ppasler = {};

De.Ppasler.Model = (function () {

/** @constructor */
function Model(param) {
   var self = this;

   self.public = function() {
    // do sth public
    console.log("public", private());
   };

   function private() {
    // do sth private
    return "private";
   }
   
   // this is what I would have done in Java
   self.toString = function() {
    return "[object Model]";
   }
 }

 return Model;
}());

var model = new De.Ppasler.Model();
model.public();
console.log(model);
```

Add `toString` Model does not work.

I've also tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu):

`Model.prototype.toString` and `self.prototype.toString` but this leads to Errors

I can't make sure `model` is defined and I want to avoid an `undefined`-check, before calling `toString` directly for loggin purpose.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36215379/2333214. `console.log` is not part of standard. You'd be better of overriding `console.log`/ writing your own log function that invokes `toString`/specific method you have defined

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I would have guessed 100% that `console.log` is a standard function... I am spoiled from Java I guess :)

Comment: This really looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @EmileBergeron as I thought this is a common approach, I didn't question it. My intention is to log the "object" in a meaningful way. As I can't mek sure its defined, I dont want to call `model.toString()`.

Comment: `console.log` with most browsers tools is intelligent and it let you explore objects directly in it.

Comment: hmm, that's a point. But I am just curious, would it be possible, although the standard might be better?

Comment: `console.log` doesn't necessarily calls `toString` but `alert` does for example.

Comment: I see, could you provide the last 3 comments as an answer and I will accept it... confusing JS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers tools provide an intelligent `console.log` that let you explore objects directly, so there's no need to override `toString`.

[image: console.log demo with class]

Even if you would override `toString` on your object, most browsers implementation of `console.log` don't call `toString` on the passed objects.

Something like `alert` would do what you expect.