# Is there a way to override an object property to turn it into something special

Tags: javascript

I have strange but interesting question and I will start right from examples.

Imagine I have an object which looks like that:

```
const stringEvaluate = {
    toString: () => 'Im object'
}
```

Now I can create string using this object

```
stringEvaluate + ' stringified'

// Im object stringified
```

And also I can do something like that:

```
const numberEvaluate = {
    valueOf: () => 1337
}
```

And turn this object into:

```
numberEvaluate + 682

// 2019
```

My questions is: 
Can I override some object property which will help me to do something like that:

```
const evaluatedObject = {
   someProperty: () => 'I was object, but not now'
}

const magic = evaluatedObject

console.log(magic)
//'I was object, but not now'
```

Comment: It is not exaclty clear what do you want to override. Return values or whole methods?

Comment: I mean object should not return itself with a properties when I call it, but it will return other type of data.
In my example `magic` will be equal `{someProperty: ƒ}`
I want it to be equal `'I was object, but not now'`

Comment: Can't you just set `magic` to the result of the function: `const magic = evaluatedObject.someProperty()` ...? Or if you were looking for something "cheeky", override `.toString()` like in your first example, and do `const magic = \`${evaluatedObject}\`` or `const magic = evaluatedObject+""`

Comment: Yeah, it should be "cheecky". I want to call it without any modifiers like template literals, etc. Just with assignment.
`const magic = evaluatedObject`

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to override JavaScript's toString() function to provide meaningful output for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu) **and** [Does console.log invokes toString method of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215379/does-console-log-invokes-tostring-method-of-an-object)

Comment: You might be able to do something with a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the console shows objects is [not specified](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#generic-javascript-object-formatting). However it would be a  really bad behaviour if the console would cause side effects when logging, or in other words: if it would call an object's method when executed. So no, what you want to do is not possible, also I don't see any usecase for that.

If you want to enrich the debugging experience, you can still add your own logger:

```
 const log = (...args) => {
   console.log(`It is ${new Date}`, ...args);
 };
```