# Typescript : How to display properties of a class with a default getter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, getter-setter

I have an interface and a class as follows

```
export interface ISample {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
}

export class Sample {
  
  private props = {} as ISample;

  public get propA(): string {
    return this.props.propA;
  }

  public set propA(propA: string) {
    this.props.propA = propA;
  }

  public get propB(): string {
    return this.props.propB;
  }

  public set propB(propB: string) {
    this.props.propB = propB;
  }

}
```

In my code, I use the class to initialize the object as follows.

```
let sample = new Sample();
sample.propA = 'A';
sample.propB = 'B';
```

But when I try printing the object using `console.log(sample)`, I get

```
props: {propsA: "A", propsB: "B"}
propsA: (...)
propsB: (...)
```

How do I get the output to display only `{propsA: "A", propsB: "B"}` when I use `console.log(sample)`?

PS : I am using `typescript 3.8.3` with `Angular 9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you wish to use the properties directly without any class object instances in between, you could skip the `Sample` class altogether. Instead you could try to use the `ISample` interface directly.

Try the following

```js
export interface ISample {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
}

export class AppComponent  {
  sample = {} as ISample;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sample.propA = 'A';
    this.sample.propB = 'B';

    // prints {propA: "A", propB: "B"}
    console.log(this.sample);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I do not know why I never thought about this before. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Sample` has a class property called `sample` which inherits `ISample`. That said it's obvious you're getting that log of `props: { propA: "A", propB: "B"}`.

If you want `propA` and `propB` to be direct elements of your class you've to inherit the Interface properly. Doing so, you'll have to set `propA` and `propB` as direct elements of `Sample` which leads to your desired log.

```
export class Sample implements ISample {
  propsA = '';
  propsB = '';
}
```

Keep in mind you've to adjust your setters and getters accordingly as long as you're using `private` states.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the toString() method:

```
export interface ISample {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
}

export class Sample {
  
  props = {} as ISample;

  public get propA(): string {
    return this.props.propA;
  }

  public set propA(propA: string) {
    this.props.propA = propA;
  }

  public get propB(): string {
    return this.props.propB;
  }

  public set propB(propB: string) {
    this.props.propB = propB;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.props;
  }
}

let sample = new Sample();
sample.propA = 'A';
sample.propB = 'B';

console.log(sample.props)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very little you can do to change the display of the class via `console.log`. This function is implemented in the browser and leaves little room to manouver. For example [implementation in FF](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-esr38/source/toolkit/devtools/Console.jsm?raw=1#180)

```
function log(aThing) {
  if (aThing === null) {
    return "null\n";
  }

  if (aThing === undefined) {
    return "undefined\n";
  }

  if (typeof aThing == "object") {
    let reply = "";
    let type = getCtorName(aThing);
    if (type == "Map") {
      reply += "Map\n";
      for (let [key, value] of aThing) {
        reply += logProperty(key, value);
      }
    }
    else if (type == "Set") {
      let i = 0;
      reply += "Set\n";
      for (let value of aThing) {
        reply += logProperty('' + i, value);
        i++;
      }
    }
    else if (type.match("Error$") ||
             (typeof aThing.name == "string" &&
              aThing.name.match("NS_ERROR_"))) {
      reply += "  Message: " + aThing + "\n";
      if (aThing.stack) {
        reply += "  Stack:\n";
        var frame = aThing.stack;
        while (frame) {
          reply += "    " + frame + "\n";
          frame = frame.caller;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (aThing instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIDOMNode && aThing.tagName) {
      reply += "  " + debugElement(aThing) + "\n";
    }
    else {
      let keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(aThing);
      if (keys.length > 0) {
        reply += type + "\n";
        keys.forEach(function(aProp) {
          reply += logProperty(aProp, aThing[aProp]);
        });
      }
      else {
        reply += type + "\n";
        let root = aThing;
        let logged = [];
        while (root != null) {
          let properties = Object.keys(root);
          properties.sort();
          properties.forEach(function(property) {
            if (!(property in logged)) {
              logged[property] = property;
              reply += logProperty(property, aThing[property]);
            }
          });

          root = Object.getPrototypeOf(root);
          if (root != null) {
            reply += '  - prototype ' + getCtorName(root) + '\n';
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return reply;
  }

  return "  " + aThing.toString() + "\n";
}
```

As you can see, for class instances (`typeof aThing == "object"`) it calls `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and displays every property.

Note that `toString` won't help - it is not used for objects (with typeof aThing == "object")

Similarly, [V8ValueStringBuilder.append](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/inspector/v8-console-message.cc#L89) in Chrome

```
if (value->IsObject() && !value->IsDate() && !value->IsFunction() &&
        !value->IsNativeError() && !value->IsRegExp()) {
    v8::Local<v8::Object> object = v8::Local<v8::Object>::Cast(value);
    v8::Local<v8::String> stringValue;
    if (object->ObjectProtoToString(m_context).ToLocal(&stringValue))
        return append(stringValue);
}
```

```
/**
  * Call builtin Object.prototype.toString on this object.
  * This is different from Value::ToString() that may call
  * user-defined toString function. This one does not.
  */
 V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ObjectProtoToString(
     Local<Context> context);
```

See also: [Does console.log invokes toString method of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215379/does-console-log-invokes-tostring-method-of-an-object)