# Why does a MongoDB document hide most of its properties when doing console log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB document, and I can access a document by doing this:

```js
let profileData;
try {
    profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
    if (!profileData) {
        let profile = await profileModel.create(aBlueprintObject);
        profile.save();
    }
} catch (err) {

}
```

(Don't mind what `message` is. Just know that `profileData` is a document in the collection `profileModel`, and `aBlueprintObject` is an default object I use to create my document.)

Now, when I do `console.log(profileData)`, this gets returned:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9"),
  userID: '801715615424315432',
  username: 'Tyrcnex#9403',
  items: [],
  bank: 0,
  coins: 1610
}
```

But when I run this code:

```
for (const item in profileData) {
    console.log(profileData[item]);
}
```

It returns this monstrocity:

```js
InternalCache {
  activePaths: StateMachine {
    paths: {
      coins: 'init',
      bank: 'init',
      username: 'init',
      items: 'init',
      _id: 'init',
      userID: 'init'
    },
    states: {
      ignore: {},
      default: {},
      init: [Object],
      modify: {},
      require: {}
    },
    stateNames: [ 'require', 'modify', 'init', 'default', 'ignore' ]
  },
  ownerDocument: undefined,
  fullPath: undefined,
  emitter: EventEmitter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: 0,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  '$options': { skipId: true, isNew: false, willInit: true, defaults: true },
  strictMode: true,
  selected: {},
  _id: new ObjectId("615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9"),
  saving: ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9
      at model.Model.save (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:481:23)
      at module.exports (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/events/guild/message.js:47:17)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5),
  '$versionError': VersionError: No matching document found for id "615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9" version 0 modifiedPaths ""
      at generateVersionError (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:437:10)
      at model.Model.save (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:493:28)
      at module.exports (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/events/guild/message.js:47:17)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
    version: 0,
    modifiedPaths: []
  },
  saveOptions: SaveOptions {},
  validating: ParallelValidateError: Can't validate() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9
      at model.Document.validate (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2344:27)
      at model.validateBeforeSave (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/plugins/validateBeforeSave.js:35:12)
      at callMiddlewareFunction (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/kareem/index.js:483:23)
      at next (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/kareem/index.js:58:7)
      at Kareem.execPre (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/kareem/index.js:87:8)
      at Kareem.wrap (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/kareem/index.js:266:8)
      at model.$__save (/Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/kareem/index.js:376:11)
      at /Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:506:10
      at /Volumes/My Files/GitHub/discordbots/fardbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
}
false
validate
{
  _id: new ObjectId("615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9"),
  userID: '801715615424315432',
  username: 'Tyrcnex#9403',
  items: [],
  bank: 0,
  coins: 1610
}
true
<ref *1> NativeConnection {
  base: Mongoose {
    connections: [ [Circular *1] ],
    models: { ProfileModels: Model { ProfileModels } },
    events: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    options: {
      pluralization: true,
      autoIndex: true,
      autoCreate: true,
      [Symbol(mongoose:default)]: true
    },
    _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
    Schema: [Function: Schema] {
      reserved: [Object: null prototype],
      Types: [Object],
      ObjectId: [Function]
    },
    model: [Function (anonymous)],
    plugins: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ]
  },
  collections: {
    profilemodels: Collection {
      collection: [Collection],
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      modelName: 'ProfileModels',
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'profilemodels',
      collectionName: 'profilemodels',
      conn: [Circular *1],
      queue: [],
      buffer: false,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    }
  },
  models: { ProfileModels: Model { ProfileModels } },
  config: {},
  replica: false,
  options: null,
  otherDbs: [],
  relatedDbs: {},
  states: [Object: null prototype] {
    '0': 'disconnected',
    '1': 'connected',
    '2': 'connecting',
    '3': 'disconnecting',
    '99': 'uninitialized',
    disconnected: 0,
    connected: 1,
    connecting: 2,
    disconnecting: 3,
    uninitialized: 99
  },
  _readyState: 1,
  _closeCalled: undefined,
  _hasOpened: true,
  plugins: [],
  id: 0,
  _queue: [],
  _listening: false,
  _connectionString: 'mongodb+srv://Tyrcnex:X.split(X)@fardbotdb.a4h1i.mongodb.net/botdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
  _connectionOptions: { driverInfo: { name: 'Mongoose', version: '6.0.7' }, tls: true },
  client: MongoClient {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    s: {
      url: 'mongodb+srv://Tyrcnex:X.split(X)@fardbotdb.a4h1i.mongodb.net/botdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      sessions: Set(0) {},
      bsonOptions: [Object],
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace],
      options: [Getter],
      readConcern: [Getter],
      writeConcern: [Getter],
      readPreference: [Getter],
      logger: [Getter]
    },
    topology: Topology {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 25,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      bson: [Object: null prototype],
      s: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(waitQueue)]: [Denque]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      hosts: [Array],
      srvHost: 'fardbotdb.a4h1i.mongodb.net',
      credentials: [MongoCredentials],
      compressors: [Array],
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      dbName: 'botdb',
      directConnection: false,
      metadata: [Object],
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000,
      loadBalanced: false,
      localThresholdMS: 15,
      logger: [Logger],
      maxIdleTimeMS: 0,
      maxPoolSize: 100,
      minPoolSize: 0,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      monitorCommands: false,
      noDelay: true,
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      tls: true,
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0,
      zlibCompressionLevel: 0,
      userSpecifiedAuthSource: false,
      userSpecifiedReplicaSet: false,
      replicaSet: 'atlas-rmab87-shard-0'
    }
  },
  '$initialConnection': Promise { [Circular *1] },
  db: Db {
    s: {
      client: [MongoClient],
      options: [Object],
      logger: [Logger],
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      bsonOptions: [Object],
      pkFactory: [Object],
      readConcern: undefined,
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace]
    }
  },
  host: 'fardbotdb-shard-00-02.a4h1i.mongodb.net',
  port: 27017,
  name: 'botdb'
}
undefined
801715615424315432
1610
0
Tyrcnex#9403
[]
new ObjectId("615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9")
undefined
615023dd2d00db6f8bef1ea9
Schema {
  obj: {
    userID: { type: [Function: String], require: true, unique: true },
    coins: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    bank: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    username: { type: [Function: String], default: 'Username' },
    items: { type: [Function: Array], default: [] }
  },
  paths: {
    userID: SchemaString {
      enumValues: [],
      regExp: null,
      path: 'userID',
      instance: 'String',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaStringOptions],
      _index: [Object],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    coins: SchemaNumber {
      path: 'coins',
      instance: 'Number',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaNumberOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: 0,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    bank: SchemaNumber {
      path: 'bank',
      instance: 'Number',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaNumberOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: 0,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    username: SchemaString {
      enumValues: [],
      regExp: null,
      path: 'username',
      instance: 'String',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaStringOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: 'Username',
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    items: SchemaArray {
      schemaOptions: [Object],
      casterConstructor: [Function],
      caster: [Mixed],
      '$embeddedSchemaType': [Mixed],
      '$isMongooseArray': true,
      path: 'items',
      instance: 'Array',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaArrayOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: [Function],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    _id: ObjectId {
      path: '_id',
      instance: 'ObjectID',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [Array],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaObjectIdOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: [Function],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    __v: SchemaNumber {
      path: '__v',
      instance: 'Number',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaNumberOptions],
      _index: null,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    }
  },
  aliases: {},
  subpaths: {
    'items.$': Mixed {
      path: 'items.$',
      instance: 'Mixed',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: SchemaTypeOptions {},
      _index: null,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true,
      [Symbol(mongoose:schema_mixed)]: true
    }
  },
  virtuals: {
    id: VirtualType {
      path: 'id',
      getters: [Array],
      setters: [],
      options: {}
    }
  },
  singleNestedPaths: {},
  nested: {},
  inherits: {},
  callQueue: [],
  _indexes: [],
  methods: {},
  methodOptions: {},
  statics: {},
  tree: {
    userID: { type: [Function: String], require: true, unique: true },
    coins: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    bank: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    username: { type: [Function: String], default: 'Username' },
    items: { type: [Function: Array], default: [] },
    _id: { auto: true, type: 'ObjectId' },
    __v: [Function: Number],
    id: VirtualType {
      path: 'id',
      getters: [Array],
      setters: [],
      options: {}
    }
  },
  query: {},
  childSchemas: [],
  plugins: [
    { fn: [Function (anonymous)], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function (anonymous)], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function (anonymous)], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function: trackTransaction], opts: [Object] }
  ],
  '$id': 1,
  mapPaths: [],
  s: { hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Map], _posts: [Map] } },
  _userProvidedOptions: {},
  options: {
    typeKey: 'type',
    id: true,
    _id: true,
    validateBeforeSave: true,
    read: null,
    shardKey: null,
    discriminatorKey: '__t',
    autoIndex: null,
    minimize: true,
    optimisticConcurrency: false,
    versionKey: '__v',
    capped: false,
    bufferCommands: true,
    strict: true,
    pluralization: true
  },
  '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
  _requiredpaths: [],
  _indexedpaths: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ]
}
Schema {
  obj: {
    userID: { type: [Function: String], require: true, unique: true },
    coins: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    bank: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    username: { type: [Function: String], default: 'Username' },
    items: { type: [Function: Array], default: [] }
  },
  paths: {
    userID: SchemaString {
      enumValues: [],
      regExp: null,
      path: 'userID',
      instance: 'String',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaStringOptions],
      _index: [Object],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    coins: SchemaNumber {
      path: 'coins',
      instance: 'Number',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaNumberOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: 0,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    bank: SchemaNumber {
      path: 'bank',
      instance: 'Number',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaNumberOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: 0,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    username: SchemaString {
      enumValues: [],
      regExp: null,
      path: 'username',
      instance: 'String',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaStringOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: 'Username',
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    items: SchemaArray {
      schemaOptions: [Object],
      casterConstructor: [Function],
      caster: [Mixed],
      '$embeddedSchemaType': [Mixed],
      '$isMongooseArray': true,
      path: 'items',
      instance: 'Array',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaArrayOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: [Function],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    _id: ObjectId {
      path: '_id',
      instance: 'ObjectID',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [Array],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaObjectIdOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: [Function],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    __v: SchemaNumber {
      path: '__v',
      instance: 'Number',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaNumberOptions],
      _index: null,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    }
  },
  aliases: {},
  subpaths: {
    'items.$': Mixed {
      path: 'items.$',
      instance: 'Mixed',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: SchemaTypeOptions {},
      _index: null,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true,
      [Symbol(mongoose:schema_mixed)]: true
    }
  },
  virtuals: {
    id: VirtualType {
      path: 'id',
      getters: [Array],
      setters: [],
      options: {}
    }
  },
  singleNestedPaths: {},
  nested: {},
  inherits: {},
  callQueue: [],
  _indexes: [],
  methods: {},
  methodOptions: {},
  statics: {},
  tree: {
    userID: { type: [Function: String], require: true, unique: true },
    coins: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    bank: { type: [Function: Number], default: 0 },
    username: { type: [Function: String], default: 'Username' },
    items: { type: [Function: Array], default: [] },
    _id: { auto: true, type: 'ObjectId' },
    __v: [Function: Number],
    id: VirtualType {
      path: 'id',
      getters: [Array],
      setters: [],
      options: {}
    }
  },
  query: {},
  childSchemas: [],
  plugins: [
    { fn: [Function (anonymous)], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function (anonymous)], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function (anonymous)], opts: [Object] },
    { fn: [Function: trackTransaction], opts: [Object] }
  ],
  '$id': 1,
  mapPaths: [],
  s: { hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Map], _posts: [Map] } },
  _userProvidedOptions: {},
  options: {
    typeKey: 'type',
    id: true,
    _id: true,
    validateBeforeSave: true,
    read: null,
    shardKey: null,
    discriminatorKey: '__t',
    autoIndex: null,
    minimize: true,
    optimisticConcurrency: false,
    versionKey: '__v',
    capped: false,
    bufferCommands: true,
    strict: true,
    pluralization: true
  },
  '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
  _requiredpaths: [],
  _indexedpaths: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ]
}
<ref *1> Collection {
  collection: Collection {
    s: {
      db: [Db],
      options: [Object],
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace],
      pkFactory: [Object],
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      bsonOptions: [Object],
      readConcern: undefined,
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      slaveOk: false
    }
  },
  Promise: [Function: Promise],
  modelName: 'ProfileModels',
  _closed: false,
  opts: {
    autoIndex: true,
    autoCreate: true,
    schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
    capped: false,
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    '$wasForceClosed': undefined
  },
  name: 'profilemodels',
  collectionName: 'profilemodels',
  conn: <ref *2> NativeConnection {
    base: Mongoose {
      connections: [Array],
      models: [Object],
      events: [EventEmitter],
      options: [Object],
      _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
      Schema: [Function],
      model: [Function (anonymous)],
      plugins: [Array]
    },
    collections: { profilemodels: [Circular *1] },
    models: { ProfileModels: Model { ProfileModels } },
    config: {},
    replica: false,
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    relatedDbs: {},
    states: [Object: null prototype] {
      '0': 'disconnected',
      '1': 'connected',
      '2': 'connecting',
      '3': 'disconnecting',
      '99': 'uninitialized',
      disconnected: 0,
      connected: 1,
      connecting: 2,
      disconnecting: 3,
      uninitialized: 99
    },
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: undefined,
    _hasOpened: true,
    plugins: [],
    id: 0,
    _queue: [],
    _listening: false,
    _connectionString: 'mongodb+srv://Tyrcnex:X.split(X)@fardbotdb.a4h1i.mongodb.net/botdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    _connectionOptions: { driverInfo: [Object], tls: true },
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      topology: [Topology],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    '$initialConnection': Promise { [Circular *2] },
    db: Db { s: [Object] },
    host: 'fardbotdb-shard-00-02.a4h1i.mongodb.net',
    port: 27017,
    name: 'botdb'
  },
  queue: [],
  buffer: false,
  emitter: EventEmitter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
<ref *1> Collection {
  collection: Collection {
    s: {
      db: [Db],
      options: [Object],
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace],
      pkFactory: [Object],
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      bsonOptions: [Object],
      readConcern: undefined,
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      slaveOk: false
    }
  },
  Promise: [Function: Promise],
  modelName: 'ProfileModels',
  _closed: false,
  opts: {
    autoIndex: true,
    autoCreate: true,
    schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
    capped: false,
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    '$wasForceClosed': undefined
  },
  name: 'profilemodels',
  collectionName: 'profilemodels',
  conn: <ref *2> NativeConnection {
    base: Mongoose {
      connections: [Array],
      models: [Object],
      events: [EventEmitter],
      options: [Object],
      _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
      Schema: [Function],
      model: [Function (anonymous)],
      plugins: [Array]
    },
    collections: { profilemodels: [Circular *1] },
    models: { ProfileModels: Model { ProfileModels } },
    config: {},
    replica: false,
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    relatedDbs: {},
    states: [Object: null prototype] {
      '0': 'disconnected',
      '1': 'connected',
      '2': 'connecting',
      '3': 'disconnecting',
      '99': 'uninitialized',
      disconnected: 0,
      connected: 1,
      connecting: 2,
      disconnecting: 3,
      uninitialized: 99
    },
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: undefined,
    _hasOpened: true,
    plugins: [],
    id: 0,
    _queue: [],
    _listening: false,
    _connectionString: 'mongodb+srv://Tyrcnex:X.split(X)@fardbotdb.a4h1i.mongodb.net/botdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    _connectionOptions: { driverInfo: [Object], tls: true },
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      topology: [Topology],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    '$initialConnection': Promise { [Circular *2] },
    db: Db { s: [Object] },
    host: 'fardbotdb-shard-00-02.a4h1i.mongodb.net',
    port: 27017,
    name: 'botdb'
  },
  queue: [],
  buffer: false,
  emitter: EventEmitter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function: syncWrapper]
true
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function: increment]
[Function: _where]
[Function: remove]
[Function: remove]
[Function: remove]
[Function: deleteOne]
[Function: model]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function: update]
[Function: updateOne]
[Function: replaceOne]
[Function: $session]
[Function: overwrite]
[Function: $set]
[Function: $set]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function: isSelected]
[Function: isSelected]
[Function: isDirectSelected]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function: reset]
[Function: $__undoReset]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function: handleReject]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function: populate]
[Function: $getPopulatedDocs]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
[Function (anonymous)]
```

Shouldn't these two do the same thing? Does this have something to do with `Prototype`?

All I wanted to do was compare the document to an object: if the document had something the object didn't have, the code would remove that property in the document. But right now I can't find a way to iterate through each item of the document, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of how `console.log` in node. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36216072/7866138) to know more about it.